# Error - Database 'DB_Name' does not exist or specified database server user does not have privileges to access this database magento 2

Tags: database, upgrade, setup-upgrade, magento2.4.4

I am facing an error after upgrading Magento 2.3.6 to Magento 2.4.4-beta4 version.

Error - `Database 'DB_Name' does not exist or specified database server user does not have privileges to access this database.`

Please check below screenshot:
[image]

> If any Idea please suggest me, Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Seems like issue in db permissions. You cab try to mysql connect via corephp file just to confirm if connecvtivity works

Comment: @Gagan, I am getting this error there after connecting corephp file with mysql. Error -Error: Undefined constant "Magento\Framework\Encryption\Adapter\SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES" in vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Adapter\SodiumChachaIetf.php:59

Comment: Can you update in question how are you trying, I am just saying to have mysql_connect using a corephp file.